# Reclassifying string variable in ArcGIS Field Calculator with Python Parser?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, reclassify, if-else

I am trying to calculate a roadway pedestrian restriction based on its functional class, using if/else logic in Python. Every time I enter this, it only turns up 'No'. The categories are strings, and I am hoping to return strings. I have double-checked that the arguments for the values in FUNC_CLASS are accurate, so I am not sure why it will only turn up 'No's. I'm new to Python.

Codeblock:

```
def Reclass(function):
  if (function =="U / FWY OR EXP") or (function =="R / INTERSTATE") or (function =="U / INTERSTATE"):
    return 'Yes'
  else:
    return 'No'
```

Expression:

```
Reclass ( !FUNC_CLASS! )
```

Comment: What are the values which are feeding into the function?  I'd personally use Python to its fullest in the comparison: `if (function in ['U / FWY OR EXP','R / INTERSTATE','U / INTERSTATE']):`